# Reusable State Definition in Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, etl, aws-step-functions

We are creating a workflow composed of multiple SQL Operations(Aggregations, Transposes etc.) via AWS Step functions. Every operation is modelled as a separate Lambda which houses the SQL query.

Now, every query accepts its input parameters from the state machine, so every lambda task is as below:

```
"SQLQueryTask": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Parameters": {
        "param1.$": "$$.Execution.Input.param1",
        "param2.$": "$$.Execution.Input.param2"
    },
    "Resource": "LambdaArn",
    "End": true
}
```

The Parameters block thus repeats for every SQLQuery node.
Added to this since Lambdas can fail intermittently and we would like to retry for them ; we also need to have below retry block in every State:

```
"Retry": [ {
   "ErrorEquals": [ "Lambda.ServiceException", "Lambda.AWSLambdaException", "Lambda.SdkClientException"],
   "IntervalSeconds": 2,
   "MaxAttempts": 6,
   "BackoffRate": 2
} ]
```

This is making the state definition very complex. Is there No way to extract out the common part of state definition to a reusable piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be using AWS CDK (https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/)

This allows developers to define higher-level abstractions of resources, which can easily be reused.

There are some example here that could be helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-readme.html